# Как в Python обновлять значения второго словаря, если он получает значение из первого словаря, при этом значения первого меняются динамически

Tags: python, словари

Существует два словаря каждый в своей переменной в отдельном файле.
Словарь в переменной date_list обновляется динамически "Изменяются только значения ключей "start_date" и "end_date" и "second_date", все остальное неизменно.

Второй словарь "dict_scripts" берет эти значения и по ним должен запускать SQL скрипты.
Но проблема состоит в том что при изменении дат в первом словаре, во второй они не "подтягиваются" и в итоге выводят значения по умолчанию.
Каким образом это можно исправить? Есть ли способ заставить второй словарь принимать обновленные значение из первого?
Желательно это сделать так, что бы не изменять структуру.

```
date_list = {
    'data1': {
        "start_date": '2022-07-01',
        "end_date": '2022-07-05'
        },

    'data2': {
        "start_date": '2022-07-06',
        "end_date": '2022-07-10' 
        },

    'data3': {
        "start_date": '2022-07-09',
        "end_date": '2022-07-15',
        "second_date": '2022-07-15'
        }
}

dict_scripts = {
                'data1': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data1']['start_date']}') and ('{date_list['data1']['end_date']}')
                            ''',


                'data2': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data2']["start_date"]}') and ('{date_list['data2']['end_date']}')
                            ''',


                'data3': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data3']["start_date"]}') and ('{date_list['data3']['end_date']}')
                            '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был решен простым переопределением второго словаря после изменения первого просто обернув второй в функцию и в последующих ее вызовах.

```
def get_dict_scripts(date_list):
    return {
                'data1': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data1']['start_date']}') and ('{date_list['data1']['end_date']}')
                            ''',
                'data2': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data2']["start_date"]}') and ('{date_list['data2']['end_date']}')
                            ''',
                'data3': f'''select * from pc
                            where dt between ('{date_list['data3']["start_date"]}') and ('{date_list['data3']['end_date']}')
                            '''
    }
```